# How to import class from one subfolder into another in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

So, I have the following folder structure ;

```
Root/
--outlook/
----outlook.py
--test/
----test.py
```

`outlook.py` contains a  class named `Outlook`.

I am trying to import `Outlook` class in `test.py` file as follows -

```
from .outlook import Outlook

outlook = Outlook()
```

I am running the script from Root folder as - `python test/test.py`

This results in error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .outlook.outlook import Outlook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.outlook'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Please help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath/471168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative import paths will work only if the child module is being loaded from within the parent module:

```
from Root.test.test import some_function
```

If you want to use components from two different child modules together and as standalone scripts I would suggest using non relative import paths:

```
from Root.outlook.outlook import Outlook
```

You will need to have the module Root in a folder included in your PYTHON_PATH environment variable

Also don't forget to add the **init**.py to all the folders

```
some_directory/
    Root/
        __init__.py
        outlook/
            __init__.py
            outlook.py
        test/
            __init__.py
            test.py
```

EDIT1: 
Depending on how you want to import from inside test.py you can face 2 different scenarios

```
from Root.outlook.outlook import Outlook
```

will require the 'Root' directory to be accessible by python

```
PYTHON_PATH="...:...:/path_to_some_directory_that_contains_Root"
```

while

```
from outlook.outlook import Outlook
```

will required

```
PYTHON_PATH="...:...:/path_to_Root"
```

the ... indicates other paths already present in the environment variable which you should leave as they are. 
The 'adding to the PYTHON_PATH represent the manual way to quickly achieve your desired result. In reality, what you should do when working with a module is install it, by using a 'setup.py' script with disutils inside the Root directory and the command

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Hi, If I have to include the path to Root directory in my Pythonpath, then isn't it a bit problematic ? Because for every new project, I'll need to include it's top level directory in the PythonPath ?

Comment: I have activated  my virtualenv and then used - `set PYTHON_PATH = 'path to root directory' `. But it did not work.

Comment: Depending on how you are loading the module, you will wan't to include the top directory or the one above. For 'from Root.outlook' you want to include the folder that contains Root and not Root itself. For 'from outlook import' you instead have to include Root. Anyway I agree this is inconvenient, I updated my answer with a better practice and some more explanation

Answer (score 0):

you are importing wrong.

```
from outlook.outlook import Outlook
```

`Root/
--outlook/
----outlook.py
--test/
----test.py`

In your case you are checking inside the outlook folder so you have to point to the file as well.

Comment: I have tried to import the Outlook class as you mentioned but it resulted in same error when I did - `python test/test.py` . Error - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'outlook'`